# Do angels sing?

Tags: talmud-gemara, song-poetry, malach-angel

After reading the last Tosfos on Chullin 91b ( http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=91b&format=text) I wondered if angels sing? Is there an explicit source in Tanach that they sing? Is this drasha (cited in Chullin) the only source that angels sing or is there other evidence that they sing? (Note: I mean sing, not call out, not shout, not speak)

Comment: I would not assume that the term "אומרים שירה" means that angels actually ***sing*** their praise.

Comment: @jake: אומרים שירה, at least sometimes, is indeed used in the sense of "singing." The Gemara (Berachos 54b) thus describes how the Jews אמרו שירה about the well, where the Torah itself uses the expression אז ישיר ישראל (Num. 21:17).

Comment: @Alex, how do you know that that (about the well) refers to singing as opposed to reciting poetry? (I assume that that was the questioner's point. Perhaps you can correct me if I'm wrong, Curiouser. If you're seeking more sources (i.e. beyond _Chulin_) for angels doing _shira_ then I'm pretty sure they're plentiful, e.g. _M'gila_ 10:2.)

Comment: @msh210, I guess it's possible, but then wouldn't it use a verb like אמר or דבר instead (as in Deut. 31:30, וידבר משה... את דברי השירה הזאת)?

Comment: @msh210, Also, the term "אז ישיר משה" is used to refer to the Shiras Hayam, which sounds like it was a song, since it was accompanied by musical instruments: ותצאן כל הנשים אחריה בתפים ובמחלת

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's surprisingly hard to find a good source in תנ"ך for this. I think the best one is איוב לח:ו-ז או מי ירה עבן פנתה ברן יחד כוכבי בקר  ויריעו כל בני אלהים ("... or who laid the foundation [of the earth], when the morning stars sang and the 'benei elohim' shouted for joy?") Rashi there says that this refers to the time when the morning stars were created. Of course, you would then have to identify the morning stars with angels, when in fact the classical commentators seem to assume that they're actually stars (and Malbim says that this is the "music of the spheres"). Otherwise this is in fact an anti-proof, because the בני אלהים are identified (e.g., by the Targum, Metzudat David, and Metzudat Tzion) as being angels - and *they* only shout!

Furthermore, these lines are actually quoted by our Gemara ("ואין מה"ש אומרים שירה למעלה עד שיאמרו ישראל למטה שנאמר ברן יחד כוכבי בקר והדר ויריעו כל בני אלהים") which understands (see Rashi there) the כוכבים to be the Jews, presumably based on the blessings given to אברהם אבינו, and the Gemara midrashically interprets this to mean that the Jews get to "sing" the Shema before the angels sing, say, or chant קדוש.

So my answer is: there is *no* passage in תנ"ך that explicitly says angels sing, even though there are *many* places where it says humans sang, must sing, or will sing! And none the less, if you ask anyone what angels do, they will tell you that they sing שירה!

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 6:3  שרפים עמדים...וקרא זה אל זה ואמר קדוש קדוש קדוש 
This is not explicitly singing, but is usually considered as such.

Of course, there are many references to angles singing in the Midrash, as Megillah 10b (singing at Yam Suf).

Answer (score 0):

בראשית רבה עח

"וַיֹּאמֶר שַׁלְּחֵנִי כִּי עָלָה הַשָּׁחַר" כתיב (איכה ג,): "חדשים לבקרים רבה אמונתך" אר"ש בר אבא על שאתה מחדשנו בכל בקר ובקר אנו יודעים שאמונתך רבה להחיות לנו את המתים א"ר אלכסנדרי ממה שאתה מחדשנו בבוקרן של מלכיות אנו יודעים שאמונתך רבה לגאלנו ר' חלבו בשם ר"ש בר נחמן אמר לעולם אין כת של מעלה מקלסת ושונה, **אלא בכל יום בורא הקב"ה כת של מלאכים חדשה והן אומרים שירה חדשה לפניו והולכין להם**. א"ר ברכיה השבתי את ר' חלבו והא כתיב ויאמר שלחני כי עלה השחר והגיע זמני לומר שירה א"ל חנוקא סברת למחנקני אמרית מה הוא דין דכתיב ויאמר שלחני כי עלה השחר א"ל זה מיכאל וגבריאל שהן שרים של מעלה דכולא מתחלפין ואינון לא מתחלפין. אנדריינוס שחיק טמיא שאל את ר"י בן חנניה א"ל אתם אומרים אין כת של מעלה מקלסת ושונה אלא בכל יום ויום הקב"ה בורא כת של מלאכים חדשים והן אומרים שירה לפניו והולכין להן א"ל הין א"ל ולאן אינון אזלין אמר מן הן דאיתבריין א"ל ומן אן הן איתבריין א"ל מן נהר דינור א"ל ומה עסק דנהר דינור א"ל כהדין ירדנא דלא פסיק לא ביממא ולא בליליא א"ל ומן אן הוא אתי א"ל מן זיעתהון דחייתא דאינון מזיעין מן טעינון כורסיא דהקב"ה א"ל סונקתדרון שלו והא הדין ירדנא מהלך ביממא ולית הוא מהלך בליליא אמר נטר הוינא בבית פעור כמה דהוה מהלך ביממא מהלך בליליא. ר"מ ור"י ור"ש, ר"מ אומר מי גדול השומר או הנשמר מן מה דכתיב (תהלים צא) כי מלאכיו יצוה לך לשמרך הוי הנשמר גדול מן השומר ר"י אומר מי גדול הנושא או הנישא מן מה דכתיב (שם) על כפים ישאונך הוי הנישא גדול מן הנושא ר"ש אמר מן מה דכתיב ויאמר שלחני הוי המשלח גדול מן המשתלח: